# Best practice to store current user data into vue store from local storage?

Tags: authentication, vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I need to fill a currentUser object,with id, username, picture, etc..,  in vue store from the local storage when i open the app, if there is a user in the local storage of course.
I want to know the best way to acomplish this, so I can use that currentUser in all views and components.
I'm sorry that there is no code because it is only a question.
Using vue-router, vue-x.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create `vuex` store, create [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html), and when your app loads, read from localStorage and `commit()` the user to the store

Comment: You can also create update your user mutation to save to localStorage, so you always have up to date value in local storage.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You can post the answer with the explanation on how you solved this issue (in more details) :)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but the answer could be useful anyway.
I used `vuex-persist` library to automatically save vuex state in local storage (others can be used, e.g. session storage).
So every operation could be done in vuex, without directly load from and save to local storage